# Name of multi-line curly left brace for functions

Tags: functions, notation, boolean-algebra

Is there a name for (or somewhere I can find more information about) the lone multi-line left curly brace used to indicate varying results depending on conditions for a function?

Examples:

[image: Iverson Bracket]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise what you're after?

Comment: @Mr.Chip Yes. That was quick. Why don't you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned above, ["piecewise"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) is probably what you're after. :)